# How to check value alrady exists on table using Hibernate&Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi im having this  method on my controller.What i want is when i pass a place name it must check whether is exists or not..if it is exists return true else false

```
 @Override
        @Transactional
        public boolean alreadyExists(String place) {
            boolean flag=false;
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Place where place_Name='$"+place+"'");

            return flag;
        }
```

Comment: ...Do you have any strong, convincing reason why you're using string concatenation instead of the `:placeHolder` syntax for Hibernate?  I ask this because this query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any assertions against the correctness or validity of your existing query...

There's a simple way to do it:  if you're expecting that only one `Place` exists *ever*, then you can use [`uniqueResult`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29), which will either return the instance of the entity if it exists, or `null` if it doesn't:

```
@Tranasctional
public boolean alreadyExists(String place) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                         .createQuery("from Place where place_Name=:place")
                         .setParameter("place", place)
                         .uniqueResult() != null;
}
```

You could also get the result as a list, and check to see if the list is not empty (thus meaning that there is a result).

```
@Tranasctional
public boolean alreadyExists(String place) {
    List result = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                         .createQuery("from Place where place_Name=:place")
                         .setParameter("place", place)
                         .list();
    return !result.isEmpty();
}
```